# Find degree of branching using circular neighbourhood method matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a skeleton image. as shown on following link.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/92388309@N03/8397759970/in/photostream/

I have detected branchpoints and endpoints and labelled the image. Now I am drawing circle on each branch and I am using following code to draw a circle on each branch.

```
mn=bwmorph(y,'branchpoints');
[row column] = find(mn);
branchPts    = [row column];
endImg    = bwmorph(y, 'endpoints');
[row column] = find(endImg);
endPts       = [row column];
figure;imshow(y);
hold on ; 
plot(branchPts(:,2),branchPts(:,1),'rx');
hold on; plot(endPts(:,2),endPts(:,1),'*');
% Labeling the Branches
branches = (y & ~mn); % set branch points to zero
figure; imshow(branches);
branchesLabeled = bwlabel( branches); % label connected components
vislabels(branchesLabeled)
% Calculation of Length of Branches and Circular Neighbourhood Method for
% for detection of normal and abnormal branches.
sts = regionprops( branchesLabeled,'Area', 'Perimeter','MajorAxisLength','Centroid' );
% extract properties
% Loop for circles
for i=1:size(sts)
r= sts(i).MajorAxisLength/2 ; %desired radius
centerx = sts(i).Centroid(1);  
centery = sts(i).Centroid(2);
th = 0:pi/50:2*pi;
xunit = r * cos(th) + centerx;
yunit = r * sin(th) + centery;
figure; imshow(branchesLabeled);hold on;h = plot(xunit, yunit);
end
```

I have couple of problems with this code.

1. The circle is drawn on center line of skeleton(It is not a branch it is center line of skeleton)
   http://www.flickr.com/photos/92388309@N03/8402753918/in/photostream
2. This code is giving me number of images (One for each branch). I want circle on each branch on same image.

I want to find degree of branching by using circular neighourhood method (by drawing circle on each brach and checking how many background pixels in the circle)

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, you are drawing circles for everything in the `sts` structure. You need to figure out how to get only the branch locations in `sts`.

For question 2, you need to call `figure` and draw the image outside of the loop. Then call `plot` in the loop to draw each circle. Something like this:

```
figure
imshow(branchesLabeled)
hold on
for i=1:size(sts)
    % your other code here...
    plot(xunit, yunit);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In question 1, I am looking to draw circles on the skeleton branches and not on the center line(center line is shown in following link with blue arrow) http://www.flickr.com/photos/92388309@N03/8404495186/in/photostream I am taking ROI of this skeleton and plotting branchpoints and labeling the ROI. But as shown in question link I am getting circle on the center line and not on branch.

Comment: Also see the link below, which shows the circles are on each branch as well as on center line of skeleton. I do not want circle on the skeleton line but just on each branch. http://www.flickr.com/photos/92388309@N03/8403454589/in/photostream

Comment: Thanks. The problem is when I am doing labeling on image I am using branches = (y & ~mn); That is I am inverting branch points. That's why center line of skeleton is not completely connected. It is breaking at the branchpoint. And code above therefore considering center line as branch and drawing circle on it. But I do not have choice as BWLabel only consideres separate objects for labeling. If I do not invert the branchpoints BWLabel will not label the branch. I am new to Matlab and do not know any other way to detect a branch in skeleton. Can you please help?